# Canvas анимация чрезмерно нагружает ноутбук

Tags: javascript, анимация, canvas

Есть паттерн как задний фон, который медленно отклоняется при движении мыши. Чтобы не рисовать каждый раз паттерн я сделал некий буфер, в котором его храню. Выглядит так: первый холст находится в DOM-дереве, на нём и будет анимация, второй холст находится в памяти и содержит в себе паттерн. При помощи `drawImage()` я отклоняю задний фон.

Возможно проблема заключается в моём подходе к реализации самой анимации, т.к. каждый раз при движении мыши я создаю `setInterval` с таймингом 1000/60 и удаляю предыдущий. Пример кода прикладываю.

```js
// Скрипт заточен под 45 градусов
function timing(x1, x2) {
  return Math.sqrt(Math.abs(x1 - x2)) / 2;
}
function draw() {
  // Background
  // bufferContext.fillStyle = "rgba(13,10,21,1)";
  // bufferContext.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
  // End Background

  // Lines
  bufferContext.strokeStyle = "rgba(20,17,27,1)";
  bufferContext.lineWidth = 10;
  bufferContext.lineCap = "square";
  for (
    lineNumber = -numberOfLinesY;
    lineNumber < totalNumberOfLines;
    lineNumber++
  ) {
    let currentX = 0,
      currentY = lineNumber * spaceBetweenLines;
    bufferContext.moveTo(currentX, currentY);
    for (pieceNumber = 0; pieceNumber < pieces; pieceNumber++) {
      currentX += pieceLengthX;
      currentY += pieceLengthY;
      bufferContext.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
      let random = Math.random() > 0.3;
      if (random) {
        bufferContext.lineTo(currentX - pieceLengthX, currentY + pieceLengthY);
        bufferContext.moveTo(currentX, currentY);
      }
    }
  }
  bufferContext.stroke();
  bufferContext.closePath();
  // End Lines
}
function handleDrawInterval() {
  if (lastClientX < clientX) {
    lastClientX += timing(lastClientX, clientX);
  } else if (lastClientX > clientX) {
    lastClientX -= timing(lastClientX, clientX);
  }
  context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  context.drawImage(bufferCanvas, -250 + lastClientX, 0);

  if (Math.abs(lastClientX - clientX) < 0.1 || lastClientX == clientX) {
    clearInterval(drawInterval);
  }
}
function handleMouseMove(e) {
  clientX = e.clientX / 20;
  clearInterval(window.drawInerval);
  const drawInterval = setInterval(handleDrawInterval, 1000 / 60);
  window.drawInterval = drawInterval;
}

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas.background"),
  w = (canvas.width = window.innerWidth + 1000),
  h = (canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight +1000),
  context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  margin = 250,
  bufferCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
  bufferW = (bufferCanvas.width = w + margin * 2),
  bufferH = (bufferCanvas.height = h + margin * 2),
  bufferContext = bufferCanvas.getContext("2d");

const lineLength = bufferW * Math.sqrt(2),
  pieces = 20,
  pieceLength = lineLength / pieces,
  spaceBetweenLines = pieceLength * Math.sqrt(2),
  pieceLengthX = spaceBetweenLines / 2,
  pieceLengthY = pieceLengthX,
  numberOfLinesX = bufferW / spaceBetweenLines,
  numberOfLinesY = bufferH / spaceBetweenLines,
  totalNumberOfLines = numberOfLinesX + numberOfLinesY,
  startX = 0,
  startY = -bufferW;

draw();
context.drawImage(bufferCanvas, -250, 0);

let clientX = 0,
  lastClientX = 0;
window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas class="background"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Upd**. Добавил прорисовку только области окна, а не всего холста, поменял `setInterval` на `requestAnimationFrame`, нагрузка сильно снизилась.

```js
class Pattern {
  constructor(DOMCanvas, bufferCanvas) {
    // DOM canvas
    this.DOMCanvas = DOMCanvas;
    this.DOMContext = this.DOMCanvas.getContext("2d");
    this.DOMWidth = this.DOMCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.DOMHeight = this.DOMCanvas.height = window.innerWidth;
    // Buffer Canvas
    this.bufferCanvas = bufferCanvas;
    this.bufferWidth = this.bufferCanvas.width = this.DOMWidth + 500;
    this.bufferHeigth = this.bufferCanvas.height =
      document.body.clientHeight + 500;
    this.bufferContext = this.bufferCanvas.getContext("2d");
    // Options
    this.lineLength = this.bufferWidth * Math.sqrt(2);
    this.pieces = 20;
    this.pieceLength = this.lineLength / this.pieces;
    this.spaceBetweenLines = this.pieceLength * Math.sqrt(2);
    this.pieceLengthX = this.spaceBetweenLines / 2;
    this.pieceLengthY = this.pieceLengthX;
    this.numberOfLinesX = this.bufferWidth / this.spaceBetweenLines;
    this.numberOfLinesY = this.bufferHeigth / this.spaceBetweenLines;
    this.totalNumberOfLines = this.numberOfLinesX + this.numberOfLinesY;
    this.startX = 0;
    this.startY = -this.bufferWidth;
    //
    this.clientX = 0;
    this.currentX = 0;
    this.penetrate = true;
    this.pageY = window.pageYOffset;
  }

  renderBuffer() {
    // console.log(this.bufferCanvas.width);
    // Background
    this.bufferContext.fillStyle = "rgba(13,10,21,1)";
    this.bufferContext.fillRect(0, 0, this.bufferWidth, this.bufferHeigth);
    // End Background

    // Lines
    // this.bufferContext.strokeStyle = "rgba(20,17,27,1)";
    this.bufferContext.strokeStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,1)";
    this.bufferContext.lineWidth = 1;
    this.bufferContext.lineCap = "square";
    for (
      let lineNumber = -this.numberOfLinesY;
      lineNumber < this.totalNumberOfLines;
      lineNumber++
    ) {
      let currentX = 0,
        currentY = lineNumber * this.spaceBetweenLines;
      this.bufferContext.moveTo(currentX, currentY);
      for (let pieceNumber = 0; pieceNumber < this.pieces; pieceNumber++) {
        currentX += this.pieceLengthX;
        currentY += this.pieceLengthY;
        this.bufferContext.lineTo(currentX, currentY);
        let random = Math.random() > 0.3;
        if (random) {
          this.bufferContext.lineTo(
            currentX - this.pieceLengthX,
            currentY + this.pieceLengthY
          );
          this.bufferContext.moveTo(currentX, currentY);
        }
      }
    }
    this.bufferContext.stroke();
    this.bufferContext.closePath();
    // End Lines
  }
  renderDOM() {
    this.currentX += (this.clientX - this.currentX) / 40;
    if (Math.abs(this.clientX - this.currentX) < 0.5) {
      this.currentX = this.clientX;
    }
    console.log(this.currentX, this.clientX);
    this.DOMContext.clearRect(0, 0, this.DOMWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // void ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
    // console.log(this.pageY);
    this.DOMContext.drawImage(
      this.bufferCanvas,
      250 + this.currentX, // sx
      this.pageY, // sy
      this.DOMWidth, // sW
      this.DOMHeight, // sH
      0, // dx
      0, // dy
      this.DOMWidth, // dW
      this.DOMHeight // sH
    );
    this.penetrate = false;
  }

  handleMouseMove(e) {
    this.clientX = (e.clientX - this.DOMWidth / 2) / 10;
  }
  handleScroll(e) {
    // console.log("handleScroll");
    this.pageY = window.pageYOffset;
  }
  listen() {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMouseMove.bind(this));
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll.bind(this));
  }
}

const pattern = new Pattern(
  document.querySelector("canvas.background"),
  document.createElement("canvas")
);
pattern.renderBuffer();
pattern.listen();

function animate() {
  pattern.renderDOM();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 4000px;
 max-width: 1440px;
}
div.canvas {
 overflow: visible;
 height: 4000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas style="position: fixed; top: 0;" class="background"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `setInterval` - не самый подходящий способ анимации. Почитайте про [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: @hindmost благодарю, существенно снизилась нагрузка!

Comment: Чтобы снизить нагрузку также буду прорисовывать не весь видимый холст, а только ту часть, что в данный момент на экране. Т.е. будет выдирать из буферного холста ту часть, что нам нужна.